# zend framework 2 getServiceLocator Empty

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I've been trying to figure it out by myself reading online and applying tons of answers form here, but to no avail unfortunately.

I have two Modules on my zf2 application, one called Services and one called Agent.
Now, in my Services module everything seems to work fine, I can get my serviceLocator, hence my configuration, and work with it. In my Agent Module's controller however, I don't seem to be able to do the same.

This is part of my AgentController:

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class AgentController extends AbstractActionController 
{

    protected $serviceLocator;

    public function ValidateAction()
    {

        $this->serviceLocator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
        //... Using the config
    }
}
```

In my module.cofig.php I have the following:

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Agent\Controller\Agent' => 'Agent\Controller\AgentController',
    ),
),
```

I have tried many solutions: changing and adding methods to the Module.php, changing the module.config etc.. Where am I wrong?

Thanks,
Andrea

Comment: `AbstractActionController` already implements `ServiceLocatorAware`, you don't need to do this yourself. What error are you getting, and what code is causing this error?

Comment: @TimFountain thanks for the info. If I try to call `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');`  "I get Call to a member function get() on a non-object". It seems like my getServiceLocator is empty.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show how and where you are doing that call?

Comment: Just remove your own implementation and use the one provided from AbstractActionController. And on a different note: use proper dependency injection via controller factories and don't use `getServiceLocator()` it'll be a goner soon enough :D

Comment: @TimFountain Thanks, I have edited the code and I have left only the method called.

Comment: @Sam Thanks, I will try using that. :)

I think I have found the problem. It is my misunderstanding given by my non-existent zend experience.. I am trying to create a new object of this class from another controller/module, in fact when I call it from the browser everything works fine.
Do I have to pass the config object from the other controller or is there a way to access the config via other methods? Thanks everyone.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info about what you're trying to do? You shouldn't ever need to manually create an instance of a controller class. If you do this manually you would need to pass the service locator instance in yourself (via. `->setServiceLocator()`), but there's likely to be a better way of doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: @TimFountain Sure; apologies, I wasn't clear enough. Basically I have a soap server that uses an external class called ServicesApi to handle the requests.
From the ServicesApi, depending on what I need, I create an object, in this case of the Agent class, that needs to use the config from the local config file to connect to the db and do different actions.
Everything is working but this configuration..

Comment: What I am doing now to make it work is passing the config to the class when I use the `setClass` on the soap server. It's not elegant, but it's working for now. If anyone has a better solution I will gladly correct this ugly thing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class variable `$this->serviceLocator` is used by the controller class to hold the service locator instance. In your example you assigning the *config array* to this variable (thus replacing the service locator instance with an array). Subsequent calls to `$this->getServiceLocator()` will then return the config array instead of the service locator object, which is the likely cause of the error you're getting.

I'd suggest either using a local variable instead:

```
public function ValidateAction()
{
    $config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
    //... Using the config
}
```

or assigning to a class variable with a different name:

```
public function ValidateAction()
{
    $this->config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
    //... Using the config
}
```

Comment: this is a good point, I have changed it but unfortunately it's still giving me the same error when I create an object of this class from another controller. `Call to a member function get() on a non-object` . But if I try loading the page straight from the browser it does work. I'll set it from the other controller I think..

Comment: thanks @TimFountain, I'll accept this as the right answer since this is the right way of doing it. Cheers.